# JOpenDocument with Android

Tags: android, opendocument

I want to open an ods file from my sdcard. The file-object returns "file exists".

My whole testsnippet is

```
final String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/file.ods";
final File file = new File(fileName);
final SpreadSheet spreadSheet = SpreadSheet.createFromFile(file);
```

The last line throws a **java.lang.ExceptionInInitilializerError** at **org.jdocument.dom.ODPackage$1.processEntry**.

Is this because of a small XML library in Android?

PS: I used the **jOpenDocument-1.2.jar** as external library.

PPS: My ODS-file was created by Google Drive.

Comment: Did you get success in displaying or reading the file with jOpenDocument?

Comment: Not yet. I didn't find a way. :(

Comment: did you get success now?

Comment: The project is on hold and I didn't had time to research.

Comment: Did you get success to display for android app.

Comment: @vickyVick Sorry, I never touched the issue again. Do you still have this issue?

Comment: @mars3142 Actually my requirement is to view the microsoft office files, so i am looking for some sdk for android. Can you help me regarding the same ?